# crash application after bulid from msbuild

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, crash

this is my first post on stackoverflow. When I build my ***WPF, .NET40*** project from VS 2013 (F6 key) application run fine, but when i use msbuild to automatic build and deploy my applications, then always i have crash on start.

My msbuid code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="default">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</BaseDir>
        <BinariesDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\mui\1.0\FirstFloor.ModernUI\Build\Binaries</BinariesDir>
        <OutputDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Setup\BuildResults\net4</OutputDir>

        <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)'==''" >Release</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">x86</Platform>
        <PlatformTarget Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)'==''">x86</PlatformTarget>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks Condition="'$(AllowUnsafeBlocks)'==''">true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'==''">v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <DefineConstants Condition="'$(DefineConstants)'==''">TRACE;NET4</DefineConstants>
        <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'==''">bin\AutoBuild\$(platform)\</OutputPath>

        <MSBuildExtensions>$(BinariesDir)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildExtensions>

        <!--<SolutionFile>$(BaseDir)\Charon.sln</SolutionFile>-->
        <SolutionFile>$(BaseDir)\cmu\cmu.csproj</SolutionFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" />


  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensions)" TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlUpdate" />
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensions)" TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Zip" />

  <Target Name="default" DependsOnTargets="Clean; Compile" />

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <!-- clear output dir -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputDir)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Compile">
    <MSBuild 
        Projects="$(SolutionFile)"
        Targets="Clean;Build"
        Properties="
            Configuration=$(Configuration);
            Platform=$(Platform);
            PlatformTarget=$(PlatformTarget);
            AllowUnsafeBlocks=$(AllowUnsafeBlocks);
            TargetFrameworkVersion=$(TargetFrameworkVersion);
            DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);
            OutputPath=$(OutputDir)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

and bat file, use to run msbuild:

```
@echo off
set msBuild=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
set innoSetup="%programfiles(x86)%\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe"
rem Charon applications bulid version
set /a bulidVersion=(%date:~0,4%-2011)*12+%date:~5,2%
set appVersion=2.0.%bulidVersion%%date:~8,2%

rem MarcorpUpdater buid version AsmVersionMarcorpUpdater
set /a bulidVersion=(%date:~0,4%-2014)*12+%date:~5,2%
set marcorpUpdaterBuiltVersion = 1.0.%bulidVersion%%date:~8,2%

@echo on
rem call %msBuild% cmu\cmu.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AllowUnsafeBlocks=true;OutputPath=..\Setup\BuildResults\net45;PlatformTarget=x86;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5;DefineConstants="NET45;TRACE";AsmVersion="%appVersion%.*" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=cmu_Manual_MSBuild_LOG.net45.log /t:Rebuild

rem call %msBuild%  charon\charon.cspro`enter code here`j /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AllowUnsafeBlocks=true;OutputPath=..\Setup\BuildResults\net45;PlatformTarget=x86;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5;DefineConstants="NET45;TRACE";AsmVersion="%appVersion%.*" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=charon_Manual_MSBuild_LOG.net45.log /t:Rebuild

rem call %msBuild% cmu\cmu.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AllowUnsafeBlocks=true;OutputPath=..\Setup\BuildResults\net4;PlatformTarget=x86;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0;DefineConstants="TRACE;NET4";AsmVersion="%appVersion%.*" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=cmu_Manual_MSBuild_LOG.net4.log /t:Rebuild

call %msBuild% build.msbuild /p:AsmVersion="%appVersion%.*" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=cmu_Manual_MSBuild_LOG.net4.log

pause

rem call %msBuild% charon\charon.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AllowUnsafeBlocks=true;OutputPath=..\Setup\BuildResults\net4;PlatformTarget=x86;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0;DefineConstants="NET4;TRACE";AsmVersion="%appVersion%.*" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=charon_Manual_MSBuild_LOG.net4.log /t:Rebuild

rem call %innoSetup% Setup\setup.iss "/dMyAppVersion=%appVersion%"

@echo off
set msBuild=
set innoSetup=
set appVersion=
set bulidVersion=
set marcorpUpdaterBuiltVersion=
```

Crash:

```
Application: net.marcorp.charon.modernui.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception..
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
 at: System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
 at: System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)     at: System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
 at: System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
 at: net.marcorp.charon.modernui.App.InitializeComponent()
 at: net.marcorp.charon.modernui.App.Main()
```

Comment: can you translate the critical words in the exception and stack trace to english please? (first two lines of exception)

Comment: translated from polish to english

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you run this on a proper VS command prompt (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and without using full path to msbuild (since it is then in your PATH)?

Comment: Thank you very much! It is work! I lost over two weeks by this stupid app crash.